# Custom text after price just for guest users in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using this piece of code to show custom text after product price in woocommerce:

```
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    $price .= ' <span id="tooltips">incl. VAT</span>';
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
```

How to make that text visible just for guest users, NOT for logged in?

Thanks!

Comment: I found some code but I don't know how to integrate it into the above code: 

`function show_to_only_guest($atts, $content = null) {
    if(is_user_logged_in())
     return false;
    return apply_filters('the_content', $content);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $price .= ' <span id="tooltips">incl. VAT</span>'; 
    }

    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
```